# When I type a capital P in pages or safari, there is a bar above my keyboard that says an explicit name. How do I remove the bar and/or the name

Tags: ipad, keyboard, safari, pages

When I type "P" on pages and safari, there is a bar above my ipad keyboard that says an explicit result.

How do I remove the bar or the explicit result?

Comment: I reckon not typing that word and adding it to your dictionary all the time would help.

Comment: @RyanMcDonough It could be that an Apple-savvy troll "friend" borrowed the iPad and repeatedly typed it so that it would be added to the dictionary.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 I think we all know what happened.

Answer (score 3):

You can't remove individual words from QuickType. To clear the custom dictionary, go to Settings → General → Reset → Reset Keyboard Dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to turn off the bar via settings/general/keyboard/predictive